# Saving data in sqlite or firebase DB?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My question has 2 parts:

1- if I built an android app (Quiz app) but the questions have images (more than 50) which the best way to save data in sqlite inside the app or online DB?

2- if I built an android app (List of sentence, only texts without images) the texts is more thant 400, so which the best way to save data in sqlite inside the app or online DB?

Comment: What exactly you want to save in the Db, the Pictures ?

Comment: its 2 apps: the first one (Quiz app) i want to store questions, answers, and images for some questions. THe second app is as dictionary just save the texts and sounds files in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Question

For the quiz app, i would recommend you to to download all your questions on the first start from the internet and then save it somewhere on the phone (i think the best place is on the sd card or in a local database).

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files

### 2. Question

I think here is it also the best idea, to download it from the internet on the first start and then save it somewhere

Comment: But the data is fixed, i didn't need to update it. So why not save all data in local DB from the beginning?

Comment: First you are flexible with this solution. If you want to add Questions or update your Directonary (new spelling) you can easily do that. How can a directonary data be final.

Comment: the data is listed in Recycle View for the user

Answer (score 0):

In both case you can use online db as well as sqlite. Sqlite db basically local db, where you can store data by fetching from online db. You can use following way:

1. Fetch data from online db and store it in local db(sqlite db)
2. When populating view to the user in app, you should fetch from local db.

Comment: If I used an SQLite DB is this a bad practice if the data is big (a lot of texts)?

Comment: if your app works online or offline both, sqlite db is the best practice.

Comment: Are 50 images or more didn't slow my app?

Comment: The app size should increase when you store the data into local db but never slow the apps.

Comment: ok this is my question, the app have to be light usually.. now my app is as a dictionary with lots text data i think Sqlite is good as you said. Thank you

Comment: @k-s-b Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are legit in how you coordinate the use of online and local storage, but I would like to provide some thinking on whether to use online database at all.

Online database is used when you have a lot of data, and you don't want a bulky app filled with built-in data. It is also used for the flexibility of updating app contents without having to send regular app updates to App Store. And for the second reason, I would recommend you to alway use online database even if you are starting small now. Anyway, let's dive into both of your scenarios.

**Scenario 1**: unless there's reason to believe your user will not have internet access when they use your app, always use online storage for images, especially when you want the flexibility of updating and growing your app contents in future. Even if you have reason not to use online storage, you need to be careful with the exploding size these 50 images would cause. Each image ranges in size of **30 KB** to roughly **300 KB** (if you want the option to enlarge your image), and we haven't even included your source file yet. As of 2017, the average size of Android apps is [**15 MB**](https://sweetpricing.com/blog/2017/02/average-app-file-size/), and there should be no reason for a quiz app to go near this number.

**Scenario 2**: so it's just text now. Text is cheap. Flexibility with your app contents should be the only determining factor for whether to use online database.

Lucky for us, online database can be free and easy to use when done right. As far as I know, Google's **Firebase** has free options for low usage, and may have more lenient options for non-profit use (You will have to talk to their customer service). Even AWS's **parse-server** has free option too for low usage.